# Insert a function in a sentence to be printed with placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, conditional-statements

I'm just starting out in Python. I have a problem, I think very simple, with a function.

My goal is to print a string variable `Template_1` with a variable substring (a substring defined by the string variable `example1` or `example2`). I would like to select only one of the substring options based on user input. I have not posted the main file so as not to lengthen the question; even so it's very simple.

This code works correctly, with user input `viene_da` to function `template`:

```
    example1 = "Text 1"
    example2 = "Text 2"
    
    #viene_da is chosen with the selection of the combobox items in the main file
    def template(viene_da):
        Template_1 =  "{date}." + \
                       (example1 if viene_da == "a" else "") + \
                       (example2 if viene_da == "b" else "") + \
                       "{sujbect}, {verb}"               
        return Template_1
```

Now I would like to create a function to select the right substring and call it in Template_1.

I wrote it like this, but there are errors:

```
    example1 = "Text 1"
    example2 = "Text 2"

    #viene_da is chosen with the selection of the combobox items in the main file
    def text(viene_da):
        a = (example1 if viene_da == "a" else "") 
        b = (example2 if viene_da == "b" else "")
        return x
        
    def template(viene_da):
        Template_1 =  "{date}." + \
                       text() + \ #LOOK HERE!!!
                       "{sujbect}, {verb}"   
        return Template_1
```

Variations of this code produce errors:

- `TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: viene_da`
- `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

How can I solve this? I know that I haven't shared the complete code, but for those who are experienced in Python it will be very easy to help me, because I would just like to insert a function in a sentence that prints. Thank you.

Comment: Where have you defined `x` other than the `return`? And when you call `text`, have you given it any arguments?

Comment: @C.Nivs When I call text () I didn't give it the argument, because the argument is in def text (viene_da). I also tried to write it in text(viene_da) + \, but I get the error name 'x' is not defined. How should I define x? Also, is the return x what I really need to print a or b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're a new Python learner, for the level of code complexity you're creating I strongly suggest you familiarize yourself with [*conditional statements*](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/). They're logical structures built to handle the "if this, then that" logic you're trying to implement.

Your `NameError` mistake was trying to return some undefined `x` when you really wanted to return one of `a` or `b`. You can use conditional statements to determine which one you want, and then have `text` return it directly.

I think this modified `text` function here will accomplish what you're trying to achieve:

```
example1 = "Text 1"
example2 = "Text 2"

def text(viene_da):
    if viene_da == "a":
        return example1
    elif viene_da == "b":
        return example2
    
def template(viene_da):
    Template_1 =  "{date}." + \
                   text(viene_da) + \
                   "{sujbect}, {verb}"   
    return Template_1
```

Additionally, when you were calling `text` before you weren't passing any argument to the function. `text` has one argument in its definition, but defining arguments to a function is **not** the same as passing arguments to a function. Just because `viene_da` is the name of an argument in the definition of `template` and the name of an argument in the definition of `text` does **not** mean that `viene_da` is passed to `text` when it is passed to `template`.

**Edit:** In response to a comment from OP, when no user input is provided in the main program the following error is raised: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`

This is because the main program is calling function `template` and providing an empty string as the argument, which calls function `text` with an empty string argument. `text` returns the null value `None`, which causes an error in the `template` string concatenation.

To avoid this I see two primary options:

1. Rewrite the main program to avoid calling `template` unless the user provides one of the expected inputs
2. Rewrite `text` to return a placeholder if `template` is called without one of the expected inputs.

Which option is "correct" depends on the desired behavior of the main program. I don't know what the desired main program behavior is, so I can only offer guidance for option 2:

```
example1 = "Text 1"
example2 = "Text 2"

def text(viene_da):
    if viene_da == "a":
        return example1
    elif viene_da == "b":
        return example2
    else:
        return ""

def template(viene_da):
    Template_1 = "{date}." + \
        text(viene_da) + \
        "{sujbect}, {verb}"
    return Template_1
```

Comment: Small problem. It only works correctly if I select something in the "viene_da" combobox. If I don't select anything in the combobox (in my project it happens very frequently that I don't select that combobox), I get the ERROR TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str, because I can't combine "{date}. " + \ with text (viena_da) + \. How can I solve? I wish you didn't get this error when I don't select anything in the "comes_da" combobox. Maybe now suggest me to use try/except, but is there any better way to solve? If not, how can I solve with try/except? Thank you

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 see the modified answer for contextual information. I suggest you evaluate why and when your main program is calling the `template` function, and possibly rewrite to avoid calling it when it's not needed/useful. The bigger picture of your program's functionality is beyond the scope of this question though.